# rails, erb in javascript: how to remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have created a javascript in the  tag of my application.erb.html.
That manages an asynchronous upload of a file (actually using plupload, but that's not relevant to the question). 

The javascript code that initializes the uploader object is the following:

```
$(function() {

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(
    {
        browse_button: 'plupload_browse',
        url: <%= upload_tmp_path(:format => :json) %>'
    });

//...

}
```

As you can see in the url line, since i am in a erb page, i rely on <%= %> tags in order to pass the script the upload url. 
Now, for modularity reasons, i want to put this script in its ad-hoc .js file. 
Since i can't use <%= %> tags anymore, what is my best option to pass such a script the piece of information required?

Comment: passing variables to your js using `gon` is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it as a custom [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) on a predictable element on page, the element configured as the browse_button seems a likely candidate.

Answer (score 1):

**DOM**

The bottom line is you're going to have to pass the data to JS through your HTML

As JS is client-side, and Rails is server-side, the only way to pass data to an independent JS script (not directly rendered by Rails) is to use either something like [`gon`](https://github.com/gazay/gon), as suggested by `apneadiving`, or by setting the url in a [`data` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) in your HTML directly:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_action :set_gon

private

def set_gon
    gon.push({
       upload_tmp_path: upload_tmp_url(:format => :json)
    })
end

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= include_gon %>
```

This will allow you to call the url in your JS as follows:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
gon.upload_tmp_path
```